# Amazon S3 direct upload - How to put file size restrictions based on content type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm aware that you can restrict the file size and the content type with a policy like this

```
"expiration": "'.date('Y-m-d\TG:i:s\Z', time()+10).'",
"conditions": [
    {"bucket": "xxx"},
    {"acl": "public-read"},
    ["starts-with","xxx",""],
    {"success_action_redirect": "xxx"},
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/jpeg"],
    ["content-length-range", 0, 10485760]
]
```

But is it possible to restrict file size based on the type? For examples - `100MB` limit for `CSV` , `800MB` for `SQL` files etc. I know that this it is possible through javascript to determine file sizes but what about the direct upload?

#### Update

I'm using [S3_direct_upload](https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload) to generate the form with the presigned policy and placed that in the rails view.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. How are the presiged POST generated? They are supposed to be generated in the backend. You can send the file size and type to the backend, and let the backend to generate a proper policy.

Comment: @jellycsc I have updated the question, yes they are updated in the backend. And okay I can try that but there is no direct way of doing this through policies?